# Qt - Database programming

Tags: database, qt

What resources do you recommend for getting someone up and running in database programing using Qt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See

- [Qt Database Docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/database.html)
- [Qt Sql Programming](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/sql-programming.html) (as suggested by Christian Rau)
- This [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MySQLDBProgramming.aspx)
- [Qt video #51 on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XE2bKUAxfw) and following

Answer (score 1):

First of all the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-programming.html), which is a really good source for anything related to Qt.

I also found [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) really useful. It is the definite book on Qt and covers nearly every topic, including database handling.

Answer (score 0):

Interview is descibed very nicely in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906)

(Advanced Qt Programming: Creating Great Software with C++ and Qt 4)